# Why can't I use 32'd in constraints?

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

The following code works fine in SystemVerilog

```
program test;

class bla;
    rand int a;

    constraint cons {
        a inside {[-10 : 10]};
    }

    function void post_randomize();
        $display(this.a);
    endfunction : post_randomize
endclass : bla


initial begin
    static bla obj = new();
    repeat (10) void'(obj.randomize());
end

endprogram : test
```

However, if I change

```
        a inside {[-10 : 10]};
```

to

```
        a inside {[-32'd10 : 32'd10]};
```

randomization fails on most tools. Some tools are happy with positive numbers but fail with negative numbers.

Is it simply a bug in all tools (seems unlikely)?

While it is not blocking, I am curious to understand the reason.
Can you help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-32'd10` is out of range for the 32-bit signed `int` type.  Just stick with `-10`.

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section *5.7.1 Integer literal constants*:

```
Example 3: Using sign with literal constant numbers
-8 'd 6 // this defines the two's-complement of 6,
        // held in 8 bits—equivalent to -(8'd 6)
```

---

```
initial begin
    $display("-32'd10='b%b", -32'd10);
    $display("-32'd10='d%d", -32'd10);
end
```

Prints:

```
-32'd10='b11111111111111111111111111110110
-32'd10='d4294967286
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with `32'd10` is that it is an unsigned number and negating it remains a unsigned number larger than what a 32-bit signed number can represent. The other problem is now the `inside` range has a *low_bound* unsigned value greater than the *high_bound*, which results in a empty range.

The constraint fails because there are no values *inside* the range.

Numeric literals without a radix are unsigned decimal. But as soon as you add a radix, it becomes unsigned. There are a number of ways to keep it signed, the easiest is to write

```
    a inside {[-32'sd10 : 32'sd10]};
```